# Cannot implicitly convert type `Vuforia.Anchor' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

Tags: c#, anchor, vuforia, gameobject

I am following a tutorial from udemy but I found an error that I can't solve. My version of unity is 2018.2.21f1 nad the verson of vuforia is 7.5.26. 
This is the message that it posts: Cannot implicitly convert 'Vuforia.Anchor' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'.
The error is in the line "myAnchor = m_Positional...".
Thanks in advance :/

// Create and place a new item

```
private void PlaceNewItem(HitTestResult result)
{
    m_PlaneFinder.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    GameObject anchorGO = null;
    GameObject myAnchor = null;
    if (m_PositionalDeviceTracker != null && m_PositionalDeviceTracker.IsActive)
    {
        myAnchor = m_PositionalDeviceTracker.CreatePlaneAnchor("MyItemAnchor_" + (++m_AnchorCounter), result);

        // myAnchor.name = "PlaneAnchor" + (m_AnchorCounter);
        anchorGO = new GameObject();
        anchorGO.transform.position = result.Position;
        anchorGO.transform.rotation = result.Rotation;
        anchorGO.name = "PlaneAnchor" + (m_AnchorCounter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the object you are getting when calling

```
m_PositionalDeviceTracker.CreatePlaneAnchor("MyItemAnchor_" + (++m_AnchorCounter), result);
```

Is of a different type than `GameObject`. You could try changing it to

```
myAnchor = m_PositionalDeviceTracker.CreatePlaneAnchor("MyItemAnchor_" + (++m_AnchorCounter), result) as GameObject;
```

And see if this resolves your issue, but I think it will only become null. Most probably you need to somehow convert the Vuforia.Anchor object to your GameObject, if necessary.
Otherwise, you could try and use a dynamic:

```
private void PlaceNewItem(HitTestResult result)
{
    m_PlaneFinder.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    GameObject anchorGO = null;
    dynamic myAnchor = null;
    if (m_PositionalDeviceTracker != null && m_PositionalDeviceTracker.IsActive)
    {
        myAnchor = m_PositionalDeviceTracker.CreatePlaneAnchor("MyItemAnchor_" + (++m_AnchorCounter), result);

        // myAnchor.name = "PlaneAnchor" + (m_AnchorCounter);
        anchorGO = new GameObject();
        anchorGO.transform.position = result.Position;
        anchorGO.transform.rotation = result.Rotation;
        anchorGO.name = "PlaneAnchor" + (m_AnchorCounter);
    }
}
```